# A Problem Using Identity Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be a connected open subset of $C$ which is symmetric about the real axis. Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in $G$ s.t. $f$ is real valued on $G\cap R$. I want to prove that $f(\bar{z})=\bar{f(z)}$ for all $z\in G$.

To prove that, I applied the fact that since $f$ is hol. then $\bar{f(\bar{z})}$  is also hol. on $G^*=\{\bar{z}; z\in G\}$. Now, for all $z\in G\cap R$, and using the fact that $f$ is real valued on this set, we have  $\bar{f(\bar{z})}=\bar{f(z)}=f(z)=f(\bar{z})$. Hence $f(\bar{z})=\bar{f(z)}$ on this set. Now, using the identity theorem, since $G\cap R$ has a limit point in $G$, $f(\bar{z})=\bar{f(z)}$ for all $z \in G$.

I am wondering if my argument is correct. If so, I am wondering how to prove that $G\cap R$ has a limit point in $G$. I really appreciate your help in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct. Take $x\in G\cap\mathbb R$. Since $G$ is open, there is a $r>0$ such that $D(x,r)\subset G$. But then $x$ is a limit point of $G$. Actually, since $G$ is open, *every* point of $G$ is a limit point of $G$.